Is std::ranges::transform_view::iterator not an InputIterator?
I have the following code (https://godbolt.org/z/K7sPbjjKE):
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> fields;

void insert_many(std::size_t pos, std::span<std::string> keys)
{
    auto view = std::views::iota(0uz, keys.size())
      | std::views::transform([&](std::size_t i) {
        return std::move(keys[i]);
    });
    static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<decltype(view)>);
    fields.insert(fields.cbegin() + pos, view.begin(), view.end());
}

Note: This example is oversimplified from https://godbolt.org/z/hYTjsohTf.
I know, you don't have to use std::views::iota at all here. The question is about why the code in its current form doesn't work.
In both libc++ and libstdc++, the static_assert passes.
However, only libc++ allows the call to insert.
I am attempting to call

template< class InputIt >
constexpr iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );


From the looks of the error message (with libstdc++), std::ranges::transform_view::iterator does not satisfy InputIterator so the overload cannot be called:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1484:2: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_convertible<std::output_iterator_tag, std::input_iterator_tag>::value' was not satisfied [with >  _InputIterator = _Iterator<false>]
 1484 |         insert(const_iterator __position, _InputIterator __first,
      |         ^


Is that the intended behavior? I thought that the new std::views stuff also satisfies the legacy iterator requirements.

It's probably a bug. Incompatibilities with clang and libstdc++ pop up sometimes.

@PatrickRoberts it doesn't compile with GCC and libstdc++ either. It's possible that it is a bug, but it's not a clang compatibility issue.

Okay, then it's just a GCC bug. The problem is static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(view.begin())::iterator_category, std::input_iterator_tag>); fails in libstdc++.

Well, if I'm reading the error correctly, libstdc++ classifies the given iterator as std::output_iterator_tag and that's not convertible to std::input_iterator_tag. It doesn't have to be the same, just convertible to that. The question is then whether this classification is proper or a bug. After all, the decltype(view) even satisfies std::ranges::random_access_range, but the legacy iterator requirements are slightly different.

Both libstdc++ and libc++ are correct. The code in question is simply relying on unspecified behavior and thus is non-portable.

The difference type of std::views::iota(0uz, keys.size()) is required to be IOTA-DIFF-T(size_t), which is an unspecified signed-integer-like type ([range.iota.view]/(1.3)).
A signed-integer-like type is either a signed_integral type or a signed-integer-class type ([iterator.concept.winc]/4).
An integer-class type is one of a set of implementation-defined types (([iterator.concept.winc]/2) that supports integer operations.

That is, the standard doesn't require std::views::iota(0uz, keys.size()) to be an integer type.
Since the difference type of a transform_view is the same as that of its underlying view, it's also not required to be an integer type. Thus, libstdc++ is correct to use the implementation-specific __int128 as the difference type.
On the other hand, since the standard doesn't forbid the use of integer type, libc++ is correct as well.

libc++ is correct, but I think this should be considered a libstdc++ bug, even though it technically meets the requirements of P1522.
std::vector::insert requires that InputIt be a LegacyInputIterator:
template <class T>
concept __Referenceable = std::same_as<T&, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>>;

template <class I>
concept __LegacyIterator = requires(I i) {
  { *i } -> __Referenceable;
  { ++i } -> std::same_as<I&>;
  { *i++ } -> __Referenceable;
} && std::copyable<I>;

template <class I>
concept __LegacyInputIterator =
    __LegacyIterator<I> && std::equality_comparable<I> && requires(I i) {
      typename std::incrementable_traits<I>::difference_type;
      typename std::indirectly_readable_traits<I>::value_type;
      typename std::common_reference_t<
          std::iter_reference_t<I>&&,
          typename std::indirectly_readable_traits<I>::value_type&>;
      *i++;
      typename std::common_reference_t<
          decltype(*i++)&&,
          typename std::indirectly_readable_traits<I>::value_type&>;
      requires std::signed_integral<
          typename std::incrementable_traits<I>::difference_type>;
    };

...

static_assert(__LegacyInputIterator<decltype(view.begin())>);

fails to compile with the following error in libstdc++:
<source>:38:17: error: static assertion failed
   38 |   static_assert(__LegacyInputIterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:38:17: note: because 'decltype(view.begin())' (aka '_Iterator<false>') does not satisfy '__LegacyInputIterator'
<source>:27:16: note: because 'typename std::incrementable_traits<_Iterator<false>>::difference_type' (aka '__int128') does not satisfy 'signed_integral'

Looking at std::is_integral, it allows:

any implementation-defined extended integer types

At this point, we can conclude that in order to allow __int128 as the difference_type of a LegacyInputIterator, libstdc++ should consider __int128 to be a signed integer.
Out of curiosity, I added the following two value template specializations (I'm aware this is considered UB):
template <>
inline constexpr bool std::is_integral_v<__int128> = true;

template <>
inline constexpr bool std::is_signed_v<__int128> = true;

and this allows the original code to compile.
Changing std::views::iota(0uz, keys.size()) to std::views::iota(0u, static_cast<unsigned>(keys.size())) also allows the code to compile, and is not UB, but is also not a very satisfactory workaround to this problem.

Actually I don't think it's a bug, but libstdc++ is correct. It's a bit defective though. https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.iterators#2.2 requires difference_type to be a signed integer type, and __int128 doesn't satisfy that because it's not considered to be an integer. MSVC would also have std::_Signed128 there, which is a class type. I think libc++ only works because iota_view has a long long difference there.

The new concepts all boil down to weakly_incrementable at some point (https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.winc#concept:weakly_incrementable) which merely have requires is-signed-integer-like<iter_difference_t<I>>, so that's a weaker requirement, satisfied by iota_view.

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1522r1.pdf actually points out that relaxing iota_view like this will throw users of old functionality under the bus until they're specially accomodated. So I guess everything works exactly as intended and expected, but the way it works is dumb and annoying (on purpose).

Reading through that paper, allowing __int128 to satisfy is_integral and is_signed would not be incompatible with the goal. iota_view<__int128> can still fail to satisfy weakly_incrementable through other means, and it would make iota_view<size_t> compatible with LegacyInputIterator.

@JanSchultke thanks for making me aware of that paper, by the way. I've updated my answer to reflect my understanding of it.

The problem here is that the type of iterator being produced by std::views::transform isn't quite what the insert function expects. It needs an input iterator, but what's being generated is more like a forward iterator.
To get around this, we need to explicitly convert the view's iterators to input iterators using std::ranges::begin and std::ranges::end. This way, we're sure that the insert function will accept the range properly.

Wouldn't std::ranges::begin just pass through to view.begin()? How would this change anything?

"It needs an input iterator, but what's being generated is more like a forward iterator." A forward iterator is an input iterator.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
